# Binary literal in condition

Tags: c++, integer, implicit-conversion, short

Having following simple code:

```
...
short s1 = 0b1100000000000001;
...
if( s1 == 0b1100000000000001 )
  printf("==\n");
else
  printf("!=\n");
```

why the comparison expression to work requires the literal `0b1100000000000001` to be explicitly casted to short: `s1 == (short)0b1100000000000001`? Why just `s1 == 0b1100000000000001`? doesn't work? What's the default type of literal 0b1100000000000001 like in condition?

Comment: As specified in Blaze's answer, it's because you're using a signed short and you're setting the [sign bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) in your value. If, instead, you defined `unsigned short s1 = ....`, your if statement should work as you expect

Answer (score 2):

With signed 16 bit shorts, `short s1 = 0b1100000000000001;` won't fit. It will be converted to `-16383`, as that most significant bit (which represents a value of `32768`) represents a value of `-32768` in a signed 16 bit `short`, hence why it's `65536` lower. This is why it's not equal `0b1100000000000001` (which is `49153`). Your compiler should issue a warning here.

By saying `(short)0b1100000000000001` in the comparison you're enforcing the same conversion there, which is why it's working with that. So now you're comparing `-16383` with `-16383`.

---

> What's the default type of literal 0b1100000000000001 like in
>   condition?

According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal) it's an `int`.

Comment: "Truncated" is not quite the right word. All bits are present and nothing gets cut off. I think you mean "overflow" which also means it's undefined behavior.